# How to use System.Speech on non-English Win Vista Business

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-vista, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I´d like to try Speech recognition to controlling program. I wrote test program in C# and when I´m debugging this, an error occurred every time -

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Calling part of COM return error HRESULT E_FAIL.* 
in System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.Initialize(SapiRecognizer recognizer, Boolean inproc)
in System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.get_RecoBase()
in System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(Grammar grammar)
```

It looks the error is caused by `engine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());`
On my notebook I installed CZECH OS Vista, and maybe this is the problem that speech recognition language is not the same as OS language.

Is there a way how to developing with system.speech in non english OS, or am I wrong in some step? There is no problem in language, I´d like use english for speech recognizing, but, I cannot get english Vista or MUI language pack.

Full code is below.

Thanks a lot!

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace rozpoznani_reci_WPF
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            try
                {
                    engine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
                    engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                    engine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
                }

            catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    textBox1.Text = e.ToString();
                 }
            }

        void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text + "  ";
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation on [`DictationGrammar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx), the argument-free constructor

> Initializes a new instance of the DictationGrammar class for the default dictation grammar provided by Windows Desktop Speech Technology.

Is there a Czech language `DicationGrammar` class available on your machine? If not, you need to create one and use the other constructor [`DictationGrammar(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554225.aspx) and load one from a URI. You can also use [`GrammarBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.aspx) to construct your own and load it instead using [`SpeechRecognizer.LoadGrammar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.loadgrammar.aspx).

You might also find [this link](http://dotnet.org.za/beta/archive/2008/01/06/system-speech-recognition.aspx) useful; it's from 2008, but you *did* ask about Vista. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your post! I have a problem with this link - it´ doesn´t work. 
I couldn´t find any czech grammar. But anyway, I´d like to use english for speech recognizing, so I installed speech platform runtime and SDK 11 and language TELE (en-US), but still when I try to load grammar an error occured.